# Swift 3 setValuesForKeys Dictionary Error

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I want to fetch userid's on my Firebase database and print out these usersid's to table view. I am storing userid's in locations tuple on Firebase. But when I run my application I am getting signal SIGABRT error on line 25. Where is the problem ? Anyone help me ?

```
    chatInfo.swift
    class ChatInfo: UITableViewController {

    let cellId = "cellId"
    var users = [User] ()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Geri", style: .plain, target:self, action: #selector(handleCancel))
        fetchUser()
    }
    func handleCancel() {

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    func fetchUser() {

        Database.database().reference().child("locations").observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {

                let user = User()
                user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary) //ERROR
                self.users.append(user)

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }

        } , withCancel: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return users.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellId)

        let user = users[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = user.userId
        return cell
    }
    }
    User.swift
    class User: NSObject {


    var userId: String?
    }
```

Comment: SIGABRT (signal abort) is the code an app crashes with when an exception (a fatal error) is thrown and not handled.  Most likely something is wrong with your storyboard or nib or info.plist.

Comment: Can you test your firebase code without the View Controller. When I wrote firebase code, I had a seperate class to test things on.

Comment: Please read the exception reason. It's most likely *this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key XYZ*. XYZ is the key in your class which does not match the dictionary. By the way: There are better ways than KVC setValuesForKeys in Swift.

Comment: It's because your class of `User` does not have the keys and values of your Firebase database. It only has a `userId` so unless your user only consists of: `userId: "someString"` then you'll receive that error. If you tell us what you're trying to accomplish, there are plenty of other ways to achieve the same result (like a `Dictionary`).

Comment: @Torewin ı could not understand you. I want to fetch all my users user id in a table view

Comment: Just use a NSDictionary. Let me write you something really quick :) - what is the data structure of your Firebase?